# grep return 0 if no match

Tags: grep, return, match

Is there any bash script which can return me a result=true with command grep?

Example: There are 1000 records of 103.12.88 in my CF logs.
Can I do a grep 103.12.88 if detect 1 or more results then print/output result show me either YES or True

Comment: I had tried this but end out 

value=$( grep -ic "210.64.203" /var/logs )
if [ $value -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "I found 210.64.203"

result come out
line 2: [: too many arguments

Comment: The title of this question is a bit odd.  If there's no match, that should generally be considered a failure, so a return of 0 would not be appropriate.  Indeed, `grep` returns 0 if it matches, and non-zero if it does not.

Comment: Hi William,

Actually I prefer to have an output if not found with the result.
So, I was thinking "0" meant No/False

Comment: Hence my comment.  In the shell `0` means success.  Non-zero means failure.  That is an important convention.

Comment: Hi William,

Noted and thanks!

Comment: Since the title of the question hasn't been changed, I think it's important to have the answer to _that particular quesion_ for those who are looking it. And the answer is simple: `grep -v` does it.

I'm going to post a separate answer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The actual answer to this question is to add `|| true` to the end of the command, e.g.:

```
echo thing | grep x || true
```

This will still output a 0 return code.

Comment: No it doesn't. That forces a 0 *return*, but generates no *output* at all. Try `ret=$(  echo thing | grep x || true )` vs `ret=$( echo thing | grep -q x; echo $?; )`
The former leaves `$ret` empty. The latter loads the exit code. Maybe you meant `echo thing | grep x && echo true` ?

Comment: Nope. I want to always return a 0 return code regardless of whether grep matches or not (which in the example it won't).

Comment: exit code and output are separate things. OP says `Can I do a grep 103.12.88 if detect 1 or more results then print/output result show me either YES or True`, which is output. Your solution is fine, it just doesn't do what the poorly worded OP asked.

Answer (score 6):

The title of the question is misleading, but since it hasn't been changed, I think it's important to have the answer to *that particular quesion* for those who are looking it. And the answer is simple: `grep -v` does it: it inverts the exit code.

```
$ echo thing | grep x -vqz
$ echo $?
0
$ echo thing | grep thing -vqz
$ echo $?
1
```

Note that you need `-z` to stream the entire file as one line; otherwise, in multi-line files you'll get exit 0 whether the match is found or not. (`-q` flag is just to suppress the output.)

Credit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433711/grep-exit-with-1-if-match

Answer (score 2):

You are processing the return value incorrectly.

```
value=$( grep -ic "210.64.203" /var/logs )
```

sets `value` to the *output* of the grep, not to its return code.

After executing a command the exit code it stored in `$?`, but you usually don't need it.

```
if grep -ic "210.64.203" /var/logs 
then echo "Found..."
else echo "not found"
fi
```

If you want the value, then test for content.

```
rec="$( grep -ic "210.64.203" /var/logs )"
if [ -n "$rec" ] ; then echo found; fi
```

Or if using `bash`,

```
if [[ "$rec" ]] ; then echo found; fi
```

though I prefer to be explicit -

```
if [[ -n "$rec" ]] ; then echo found; fi
```

Comment: Rather than `if [ ! "$rec" = "" ]`, it is generally cleaner to write `if [ -n "$rec" ]`

Comment: Edited. I always use that with `[[` in `bash`, but since I so seldom use `[` it didn't occur to me to try it while I was testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
[user@host ~]$ cat ~/mylogfile.txt
no secrets here
[user@host ~]$ grepnot(){ ! grep $1 $2; return $?;}
[user@host ~]$ grepnot password mylogfile.txt 
[user@host ~]$ echo $?
0
[user@host ~]$ grepnot secret mylogfile.txt 
no secrets here
[user@host ~]$ echo $?
1
```

*Note: I'm using 'grepnot' in a Jenkins pipeline.  My previous answer used "1 - $?" to reverse the return code. But that solution still caused grep failure in the pipeline.  The above solution (which borrows from a previous "!" answer) works with the pipeline.*

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'd make it

```
echo thing | ( grep x || [ "$?" == "1" ] ) | <next command>
```

to catch any errors which may occur (disk, memory, etc.). This is especially useful if you use `set -e` on your script.

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Comment: Or to not continue, ```echo thing | grep x && exit 1```

Answer (score -1):

If you want return success on **grep** not finding a match it's easier to negate its output:

```
echo "Hello, World" | not grep -q "Friend" && echo "No match"
```

This prints `No match` since "Friend" was not found in the output.

```
echo "Hello, World" | not grep -q "Hello" && echo "No match"
```

This prints nothing since friend **was** found in the output.

Note we're using flag `-q` (as in `--quiet`) so grep does not write to output, but exits with status  0 if a match is found.

Comment: This doesn't work - there is no `not` in bash, and the second line does indeed print. Are you using a different shell?

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, it seems `not` is a program that comes with `LLVM` (which I already had installed). I'll try to gather up more information to update my answer, but thank you for noticing the issue.

Comment: Was wondering why it didn't work for me :)

Comment: A single exclamation mark `!` does what the reponder's `not` program does: it 'inverts' the status code. So `! true` exits with the status code 1 and `! false` exits with the status code 0.

Comment: @ob-ivan I get `bash: !: command not found`

Comment: @koppor The whitespace is important. Bash sees `!:` as a single token and cannot recognize this command, but `! :` are two separate tokens: a "not" and a "true".